# arm-none-eabi-g++ is trying to compile for desktop instead of arm

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, arm

I have a makefile that calls arm-none-eabi-g++ to compile a bunch of files.  If I give the files a .c extension, it works.  If I change the extension to .cc, it looks like g++ is doing the compilation instead of arm-none-eabi-g++.  I'm specifying -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb.  Here is the makefile:

```
CXX := arm-none-eabi-g++

# -I/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/include\: since we're compiling with nostdinc and nostdlib, include this directory to grab necessary files
CFLAGS := \
    -nostdinc\
    -I.\
    -I../arch/cortex-m0+\
    -I../devices\
    -I../libc\
    -I/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/include\
    -O0\
    -ffunction-sections\
    -fdata-sections\
    -Wall\
    -fmessage-length=0\
    -mcpu=cortex-m0\
    -mthumb\
    -mfloat-abi=soft\
    -gdwarf-2\
    -g3\
    -gstrict-dwarf\
    -Wno-unused-but-set-variable\
    -Wno-attributes\
    -fno-builtin\
    -fno-exceptions

objects := \
        ../libc/math.o\
        ../libc/malloc.o    

radio : $(objects)

math.o : ../libc/math.c ../libc/math.h
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c ../libc/math.c

malloc.o : ../libc/malloc.cc ../libc/malloc.hh
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c ../libc/malloc.cc


clean :
    rm radio.elf radio.map $(objects)
```

and here's the output from make:

```
marlon@marlon-Z68X-UD3H-B3:~/projects/firmware$ make

cc -nostdinc -I. -I../arch/cortex-m0+ -I../devices -I../libc -I/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -gdwarf-2 -g3 -gstrict-dwarf -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-attributes -fno-builtin -fno-exceptions   -c -o ../libc/math.o ../libc/math.c

cc: warning: ‘-mcpu=’ is deprecated; use ‘-mtune=’ or ‘-march=’ instead

cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mthumb’

cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mfloat-abi=soft’

make: *** [../libc/math.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Isn't the conventional symbol for the C++ compiler name `CXX`?

Comment: Good point.  I'm migrating the project from C to C++; I'll make that change.

Comment: Anyway, when you say "it looks like", is that what you actually see in the output? Or? I'd be rather surprised to say the least if `g++` were invoked by Make itself here. Got to wonder what's hidden away behind the `...`...

Comment: I changed CC to CXX, and now it's calling cc instead of g++ (which is weird, but still pretty much the same problem.  I'll update the question with the output from make

Comment: That makefile clearly doesn't generate that output. You have a load more flags, for one. Where is your testcase please?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by testcase?  I can post the whole makefile if it would be helpful

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Surely by now you know how to create a [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Not sure how people expect to solve problems without [this basic debugging skill](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/)!!

Comment: I'll try to simplify it and update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the discrepancy between

```
objects := ../libc/math.o ...
```

and

```
math.o: ...
```

Make has a rule for `radio` which depends on `objects`, thus depends on `../libc/math.o`. Since that doesn't exist, Make goes looking for a rule to build it. Now, `math.o` **in the current directory** is a different thing to `../libc/math.o`, so Make finds no user-defined rules for what it wants, and ends up falling back to its [implicit rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) (which build ".c" files with $CC and ".cc" files with $CXX).

In other words, your custom rules are for irrelevant targets - you can simply specify the exact path to make things work as expected, although if you ultimately want something more general it'd be worth having a look into how wildcards and pattern rules work.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had no idea this was happening.  I seem to have fixed the issue as explained in my answer, but I'll make this change.  I'm fairly new to writing makefiles.

Comment: You've 'fixed' the issue in that you've made both objects compile via implicit rules, but note that that _doesn't_ give you the dependencies on headers which you've tried to acheive. Make certainly has some non-obvious idiosyncracies and does take a bit of getting used to, but at least the documentation is small enough that you can skim through it end to end and get a fair idea, then pick out specifics as and when. I don't write many makefiles, but when I do, disabling the implicit rules is about the first thing I put in ;)

Comment: Oh yeah, I wasn't disagreeing with you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by making sure I set both CC and CXX in the makefile:

```
CC := arm-none-eabi-gcc
CXX := arm-none-eabi-g++
```